# Regex in Spring Boot YML

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have a Spring Boot web app:

In application.properties, I have this property whose value is a regex:

```
mytest.regex=^[a-zA-Z0-9()\\-=\\*\\.\\?\\|;,+\\/:&_ \"]*$
```

I inject that in a controller as below:

```
@Value("${mytest.regex}")
private String regex;
```

and print in the controller method and then compile using:

```
Pattern.compile(regex)
```

It compiles successfully without any exception and prints the below line in the console (Note the Java related escape characters are not is the output):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9()\-=\*\.\?\|;,+\/:&_ "]*$
```

Now, I replace the application.properties file with application.yml. The file content now looks like this:

```
mytest:
  regex: ^[a-zA-Z0-9()\\-=\\*\\.\\?\\|;,+\\/:&_ \"]*$
```

Please note that the regex are exact same.

The console output now is:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9()\\-=\\*\\.\\?\\|;,+\\/:&_ \"]*$
```

and the `Pattern.compile(regex)` throws `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 16`

Now, I escape the `=` in the regex as:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9()\\-\\=\\*\\.\\?\\|;,+\\/:&_ \"]*$
```

The console output is (Note unlike properties file Java related escape characters are still there):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9()\\-\\=\\*\\.\\?\\|;,+\\/:&_ \"]*$
```

and `Pattern.compile(regex)` is successful.

Now, please can someone explain:

1. Why in case of yml, the console output shows Java related escape characters
2. Why `=` needs to be escaped in yml, but not in properties

Answer (score 2):

Well,

I have been working with Regular Expressions practically five days a week - for almost a year now.

**First**, I know with 100% certainty that the open and close parenthesis are control characters that the regular-expressions compiler would expect to see escaped:

> `^[a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\-=\*\.\?\|;,+\/:&_ "]*$`

Note, I have added a backslash before the parenthesis.  Not all regular-expression compiler are created equal, but the one that I use in Java would probably want them escaped.

**Second,** The Java Compiler, and the Java Regular-Expression Compiler (built inside Java) are not the same either.  The only reason that you need to ***"escape the escape character"*** (include a ***double-backslash***) is because Java's Language Compiler compiles the code *first*, and the Java's (Run-Time) Regular-Expressions compiler runs *second*.

> If the Regular-Expression parser that is running and reading the YML
>   file is not first compiled by a Java Compiler, then you ***would not need
>   to double-escape*** (escape the escape character - a.k.a. the
>   'backslash').  Instead, only use one backslash characters in your
>   expression.

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't answer the question. The two questions I have are mentioned at the bottom of the question and those are related to the difference in behaviour between yml and properties file.

Comment: I have tried my best, sir!  **Question #1 asks about Java escape characters** ...  and I know (for a fact) that **there is only one Java escape character** - and that is the backslash.  **AND** The only characters that would ever need to be escaped are the backslash itself, and the double-quote.  **Question #2** - I have not used YML, and don't know how a YML parser "does" RegEx parse.  However, if YML uses a some other Reg-Ex language (of which there are many: POSIX, UNIX, PERL...) - I have elucidated the one I understand very well - Java's RegEx!  Could explain what's different in YML RegEx?